# nginx location wildcard proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Помогите разобраться, есть 2 сервера nginx и внутренний сайт.
Необходимо передать  путь после основного домена в секцию прокси пасс видкардом.
Подскажите пожалуйста как верно написать регулярку для этого.

Comment: Покажите конфиги и схему что куда ходит. Я не могу понять как связаны два(!) nginx и внутренний сервер